# Duplicity error: BackendException: ssh connection to SERVER_IP:22 failed

Tags: ssh, sftp, duplicity

This used to work just fine until I had to change the server ip.

I can sftp to the server. I can also run a simple [python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3635163/679318) using paramiko to connect to sftp, and it works ok.

But when I run duplicity, it fails:

```
Duplicity error: BackendException: ssh connection to SERVER_IP:22 failed
('SERVER_IP', <paramiko.ed25519key.Ed25519Key object at 0x7f8fec54f710>,
paramiko.ed25519key.Ed25519Key object at 0x7f8fec53e4d0>)
```

I tried editing `sshbackend.py`, which on my distro is `ssh_paramiko_backend.py`, as [explained here](https://serverfault.com/a/698110/112008) as a possible fix but didn't work.

The exact duplicity command is:

```
duplicity --full-if-older-than 1M [SOURCE] sftp://[USER]@[SERVER_IP] --volsize 666 --verbosity 8 --allow-source-mismatch
```

Password is being set on `export FTP_PASSWORD=[pass]`. I tried also to pass the password in the command, but I got the same error.

```
root@server:~# ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

root@server:~# duplicity -V
duplicity 0.7.06

root@server:~# python -c "import paramiko; print paramiko.__version__"
2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

does `pexpect+sftp://` work? ..ede/duply.net

Comment: Nop, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

On destination server

Add the following line to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

Then restart sshd

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

If connecting to a SFTP backup via `duplicity`and you get the "No authentication methods available" error, make sure to use the paremeter `--ssh-askpass` for duplicity.

> --ssh-askpass
> Tells the sftp/scp backend to use FTP_PASSWORD from the environment, or, if that is not present, to prompt the user for the
> remote system password. This password is also used for ssh keys that
> are passphrase-protected. Without this option the password is expected
> in the url.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/duplicity